# How do you access an nested inner function from another outer function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Please have a look at the following JavaScript snippet of code. This has to do with function scoping and hoisting in javascript. I can't call window.innermost() as it is undefined as it's not in scope.

Anyone know another way besides attaching it to the windows object. Windows Object still doesn't work in this case.

```
function outer(){
    function callback() { 
        window.innermost = function() {
            alert("hello from inner most")
        }
    }
}

(function caller() {
     window.innermost();  // this is undefined
}());
```

Comment: Nothing ever calls `callback` or `outer`, thus `window.innermost` is never set.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Edit: or rather the point of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to call both the outer and the callback:

```
function outer(){
    var callback = function() { 
        window.innermost = function() {
            alert("hello from inner most")
        }
    }
    callback(); // Call Callback
}
outer(); // Call outer

(function caller() {
     window.innermost();  // should work
}());
```

If both of these functions are *not* called *before* you run the anonymous function, then the `window.innermost` won't be defined (or undefined if you will).

Also, notice that I set `callback` as a variable, which is an alternative way of defining a function within a function.

Comment: *"[...] you can't define a function within a function with the traditional definition."* That is wrong. `function foo() { function bar() { } }` is valid and works.